# Regex replace keeping digits after comma AND the sign at the end of the number

Tags: regex

I would like to replace all characters after the first 2 digits after a comma, as well as keep the negative sign at the end of the string.

E.g. having a string of 1234,56789- should result into 1234,56-.

Using (,\d{2}).* and replacing with "$1-" does indeed keep everything until 2 digits after comma, but it doesnt keep/add the minus sign at the end of the string.

I have tried (,\d{2}).*(-) and then replacing with "$1$2" too, but that didnt work neither.

Comment: Just use `\d`: `(,\d{2})\d*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a substitution, you can use `(,\d{2})\d*` and replace with `$1`

- `(,\d{2})`: keeps the coma and the needed two digits
- `\d*`: ignore the other digits

https://regex101.com/r/dcObRO/2

Answer (score 0):

If you have a floating point number, it is better to make groups on it and rewrite the number as you desire, as in:

```
([0-9][0-9]*,[0-9][0-9])[0-9]*([-+])?
^ 1st group   two digits      ^ 2nd group (optional)
```

then you can convert it into

```
\1\2
```

as shown in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UAxANf/1)